# JOIN different data types using case statement MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sqldatatypes

I want to join t1 to t2 but the problem is i want to join a varchar to an int.
lets say they have a column called jobType and the vales for table 1 look like

```
1
2
3
4
```

and table 2 jobType Column looks like

```
a
b
c
d
```

where 1 corresponds to a, 2 corresponds to b etc.

Basically I want to be able to join job types and define that if 'a' then 1 and
'b' then 2 and so forth.

Below is some incorrect syntax but maybe it gets my point across, or maybe it just confuses the situation more...

```
select * from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
on case 
when jobtype = 'a' then 1
when jobtype = 'b' then 2
when jobtype = 'c' then 3
when jobtype = 'd' then 4
end as jobtype
t1.jobtype = t2.jobtype
```

Im sure this has been solved before but i dont know what this is called so google searching was unfruitful.

EDIT: here are tables with one of the answers provided. when i run this i get 'conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int'. any ideas on how to do a join between different data types?

```
create table t1
(id int identity(1,1),
jobtype int,
primary key (id)
)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (1)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (2)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (3)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (4)

create table t2
(id int identity(1,1),
jobtype varchar(1),
primary key (id)
)
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('a')
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('b')
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('c')
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('d')

select * 
from  t1
JOIN  t2
on case t1.jobtype
    when 'a' then 1
    when 'b' then 2
    when 'c' then 3
    when 'd' then 4
    end = t2.jobtype
```

Comment: I think you should focus on fixing your data rather than forcing a query to fix broken data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
your comment was not helpful. im migrating a poorly built database while maintaining the data as best i can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I totally agree with Gordon about fixing your data, or possibly even the structure you have it all there. Just a syntax error. Please realize this is not going to perform or scale very well.

```
select * 
from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
on case t1.jobtype
    when 'a' then 1
    when 'b' then 2
    when 'c' then 3
    when 'd' then 4
    end = t2.jobtype
```

--EDIT--

Not a big deal at all. Thanks for posting ddl and sample data. You just need to reverse the case expression here.

```
select * 
from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
on case t1.jobtype
    when 1 then 'a'
    when 2 then 'b'
    when 3 then 'c'
    when 4 then 'd'
    end = t2.jobtype
```

Comment: thank you. im migrating a poorly built database but trying to maintain the data as best i can.  my new structure does not do keys this way

Comment: I get an error stating 'conversion failed when converting the varchar value a to data type int'. did you get this?

Comment: Of course not...I don't have your tables or data. I am purely guessing based on what you posted. I think maybe you should post some table definitions and a little sample along with an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Or maybe you need the string value there instead of integer values. if that is the case just wrap the ints in quotes. "when 'a' then '1'...."

Comment: create table t1
(id int identity(1,1),
jobtype int,
primary key (id)
)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (1)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (2)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (3)
insert into t1 (jobtype) values (4)

create table t2
(id int identity(1,1),
jobtype varchar(1),
primary key (id)
)
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('a')
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('b')
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('c')
insert into t2 (jobtype) values ('d')

select * 
from  t1
JOIN  t2
on case t1.jobtype
    when 'a' then 1
    when 'b' then 2
    when 'c' then 3
    when 'd' then 4
    end = t2.jobtype

Comment: i edited my question. there is some example data with the join not working

Comment: That worked. Ashamed I didnt catch that.  Thanks for the help